# AlmaLinux HTTPD will not recognize the error with .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, .htaccess, httpd.conf, plesk

**Product version:** Plesk Obsidian 18.0.47.5

**OS version:** AlmaLinux 8.7 x86_64

The problem is Apache / HTTPD would not recognize to error its .htaccess from when editing the file at AllowOverride None to All from the httpd.conf caused to not be updated or edited when restarted the server and everything all of us are completely restarted and still issue.

Edit an httpd.conf on a root server

1. Change AllowOverride from **None** to **All**
2. Restart the server
3. Everything restarts DNS, PHP, Plesk, Nginx / Apache server, etc
   nothing works

A configuration was changed and no logs were are changed from httpd.conf at moment no error logs.

It's clearly Almalinux is caused by not being recognized at .htaccess or a missing system error. CentOS was everything perfect that I used to on Plesk and cPanel so I believe.

That would still show the *Under Maintenance* from the site.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SOfr.png)

Comment: "Change AllowOverride from None to All" - Where? You probably should not _change_ anything, but rather introduce a more specific `<Directory>` container for the `DocumentRoot` that sets `AllowOverride All` - overriding the parent config.  "Nginx"? Are you saying you deliberately introduced an error in `.htaccess` and this was not detected?

Comment: <code>/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf</code>, this is one. 

Full HTTPD code: https://pastebin.com/qcSwADk2

Yeah, it's possible, because Plesk used apache and nginx are mixed and together.